# Python negative zero slicing

Tags: python, idioms, slice

I often find myself having to work with the last n items in a sequence, where n may be 0. The problem is that trying to slice with `[-n:]` won't work in the case of `n == 0`, so awkward special case code is required. For example

```
if len(b): 
    assert(isAssignableSeq(env, self.stack[-len(b):], b))
    newstack = self.stack[:-len(b)] + a
else: #special code required if len=0 since slice[-0:] doesn't do what we want
    newstack = self.stack + a
```

My question is - is there any way to get this behavior without requiring the awkward special casing? The code would be much simpler if I didn't have to check for 0 all the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid inconsistent s\[i:-j\] slicing behaviour when j is sometimes 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753582/how-to-avoid-inconsistent-si-j-slicing-behaviour-when-j-is-sometimes-0)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can switch it from `L[-2:]` to `L[len(L)-2:]`

```
>>> L = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> L[len(L)-2:]
[4, 5]
>>> L[len(L)-0:]
[]
```

Comment: None of the answers are particularly appealing, but I think this one makes the most sense. If the expression resulting in L is short, than this is simpler then an explicit check.

Answer (score 24):

Just use `or`'s coalescing behavior.

```
>>> print 4 or None
4
>>> print -3 or None
-3
>>> print -0 or None
None
```

**Explanation (from comments):** In your case it would look like this
`self.stack[:(-len(b) or None)]` reduces to `self.stack[:None]` if `len(b)` is `0`, which in turn reduces to `self.stack[:]`

Comment: I don't see how that relates to the question.

Comment: `self.stack[:(-len(b) or None)]` reduces to `self.stack[:None]` if `len(b)` is 0, which in turn reduces to `self.stack[:]`, which is *awful* close to (but not exactly like) the expression in the `else` clause.

Comment: The only difference is that `myList[:]` is a _copy_ of `myList`. Changing a value of `mylist[:]` will not affect `myList`.

Comment: Using None works for the end of the slice, but what about the start? stack[None:] still gives the whole list.

Comment: So then coalesce with a different value there. Say, `len(self.stack)`.

Comment: At that point you might as well just use `len(self.stack)-n` (you'd be typing more using `or`).

Comment: +1, because a simple test on `n` is simpler than a *calculation* like `len(L)-n` (as in jamylak's answer).

Answer (score 2):

When you find yourself using a construct more than once, turn it into a function.

```
def last(alist, n):
    if n:
        return alist[:-n]
    return alist

newstack = last(self.stack, len(b)) + a
```

An even simpler version as suggested by EOL in the comments:

```
def last(alist, n):
    return alist[:-n] if n else alist[:]
```

Comment: You may also more simply write `return alist[:-n] if n else alist`. It may also be a good idea to copy the list *every time*: `… else alist[:]`. This actually leads to an even simpler answer, very close to Ignacio's: `return alist[:-n or None]`.

Comment: I think that if the original version used an `else` clause it would be clearer, or just as clear as the version suggested by @EOL

Comment: @jamylak, you may be right. I prefer leaving out the `else` when I can, but I admit it's down to personal preference.

Comment: @MarkRansom I agree but my preference is to always leave it in :D

Comment: @MarkRansom, @jamylak: I don't think that using `else` should stricly be down to personal preference: using an explicit `else` instead of an implicit one (as in the current version of this answer) is arguably generally better: one does not need to read the full "then" part in order to know that the `if… return` structure is actually an `if then else` structure. This makes the code faster to parse, and therefore makes it more legible (in general: there are exceptions, for instance when the `else` clause would be very long).

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be horribly inefficient, thanks to the double-reversing, but hopefully there's something to the idea of reversing the sequence to make the indexing easier:

```
a = [11, 7, 5, 8, 2, 6]

def get_last_n(seq, n):
    back_seq = seq[::-1]
    select = back_seq[:n]
    return select[::-1]

print(get_last_n(a, 3))
print(get_last_n(a, 0))
```

Returns:

```
[8, 2, 6]
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slip a conditional in there

```
L[-i if i else len(L):]
```

I think this version is less clear. You should use a comment along side it

```
L[-i or len(L):]
```