# How to avoid inconsistent s[i:-j] slicing behaviour when j is sometimes 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slice

I am creating a number of slices `[-WINDOW-i:-i]` of a list, where `i` ranges between `32` and `0`:

```
vals = []

for i in range(32, -1, -1):
    vals.append(other_list[-WINDOW-i:-i])
```

When `i == 0`, this returns a slice of length 0:

```
other_list[-WINDOW-0:0]
```

I don't want to have to do this to solve it:

```
vals = []

for i in range(32, -1, -1):
    if i == 0:
       vals.append(other_list[-WINDOW:])
    else:
       vals.append(other_list[-WINDOW-i:-i])
```

… because if I have many lists to append to `vals`, it gets messy.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: can you add your input and expected output.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One workaround for this quirk in Python slicing is to take advantage of these facts:

1. `false_ish_value or other_value` always evaluates to `other_value`
2. `0` is the only integer that is [false-ish](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in a boolean context
3. `s[n:None]` is equivalent to `s[n:]`

With those in mind, you can write your slice as:

```
other_list[-WINDOW-i:(-i or None)]
```

… and the slice will be interpreted as `[-WINDOW-i:None]` (which is the same as `[-WINDOW-i:]`) only when `i` (and therefore `-i`) is `0`.