# How to take N elements from the end of a list in Python? N >= zero

Tags: python, python-3.x

The interval for N includes zero, so a trivial slicing `lst[-n:]` is not a solution here. I am looking for something like `takeright` from Scala.

Current solution:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print(lst[len(lst) - n :])
```

Comment: What does "N includes zero" mean? its unclear what you're asking, or why `lst[-n:]` isn't a solution

Comment: @Sayse What they probably mean: if `n` is 0, they want an enpty list. `lst[-n:]` is in this case `lst[0:]`, which is a copy of the entire list.

Comment: @glglgl - Fair enough. Possible duplicate: [Python negative zero slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11337941/1324033)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your requirements, you only have to deal with the special case `n == 0`.

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print(lst[-n:] if n else [])
```

is probably the shortest resp. easiest you can have.

If you don't like that, you probably should stick with your solution.

Comment: Aren't any tools for this kind of thing there in Python functional libraries?

Answer (score 1):

> N includes zero, so a trivial slicing lst[-n:] is not a solution here.

If you want to handle the case when n is or less than `0`, then you can use [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/Booleans.html) in Python. Like this:

```
result = li[-n:] if n > 0 else []
```

Or

You can use your solution as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337989/5735010) too! (Thanks to @glglgl)